# How to access Combobox.ItemSource properties within DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

if I have DataGridComboBoxColumn in XAML

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Department Id" x:Name="comboboxColumn1"
```

I can refer to the comboboxColumn1.Itemsource in code using

```
comboboxColumn1.ItemsSource = comboboxSource;
```

If I now use DataGridTemplateColumn instead...

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Col2" Header="name">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox x:Name="Combobox2" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

how do I then set the Combobox2.ItemSource in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it *have* to be in code behind??

You are building a `DataTemplate`, which is the template used anytime WPF needs to render that specific DataGridCell. Therefore, there is never a single instance of your ComboBox, but rather as many instances as you have DataGridCells being displayed (which is why you can't actually reference the item by Name).

If I *had* to set the `ItemsSource` in code-behind, I would just put a `Loaded` event on the ComboBox and set it there.

Or if the `ItemsSource` is not static, then you can use the [ItemContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.aspx) to get the template for a specific DataGrid item, and find it through that.

But really you should set the `ItemsSource` in the XAML using a `StaticResource`, or a binding if you can, so I'd suggest figuring out how to set the binding through the XAML using a `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` binding to find whatever object contains your `ItemsSource` first, and only settling for using code-behind if you absolutely have to.

Also, the reason why `comboboxColumn1.ItemsSource = comboboxSource;` works is because you're setting `DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource`, not `ComboBox.ItemsSource`, and there's only a single object named `comboboxColumn1`

Comment: Thanks for this - I've now tried to set ItemsSource in XAML using `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding comboBoxSelections}" />` where comboBoxSelections is defined in the MainWindow as `public Dictionary<string, double> comboBoxSelections;` - the comboboxes are empty even though comboBoxSelections has items. Any clues as to why?

Comment: @ooo You need to change the source of your binding to tell it to look for the property in your MainWindow instead of the DataGrid item. You can either give your MainWindow an `x:Name` and use `ElementName=MyWindowName` in your binding, or use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Window}}` in the binding to tell it to look up the VisualTree for a Window object